# Issues with Object.toString in IE8, backbone.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, backbone.js

What is up with IE8 and the `toString` method of Objects?

I am trying to override `toString` in my models in Backbone.js, but IE8 doesn't seem to recognize that the method is there. Changing the method name to something else works fine, but why can't I use `toString`?  This works in Chrome.

```
var Foo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    toString: function(){ return this.get("name"); },
    description: function(){ return this.get("name"); }
});

var f = new Foo({name: "a foo"});

document.writeln(f.toString());    // "[object Object]", should be "a foo"
document.writeln("<br/>");
document.writeln(f.description()); // "a foo"
```

JSFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/x96mR/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you move the `toString` outside the `Backbone.Model.extend` to:

`Foo.prototype.toString = function(){ return this.get("name"); };`

It works. I would suspect that Backbone is doing some funky stuff that doesn't work as expected in IE8

**Edit (thanks to @Ferdinand Prantl):**

All properties passed into the `Backbone.extend` are added to the model's `prototype` using `for-in` enumeration. `IE < 9` has a bug where it will not copy certain properties called the DontEnumBug.

**[DontEnumBug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute#JScript_DontEnum_Bug)**

> In IE < 9, JScript will skip over any property in any object where
>   there is a same-named property in the object's prototype chain that
>   has the DontEnum attribute.

constructor, **toString**, valueOf, toLocaleString, prototype, isPrototypeOf, propertyIsEnumerable, hasOwnProperty, length, and unique will all be skipped.

Comment: Backbone icopies all properties from the prototype by the for-in enumeration.  IE skips properties with names: constructor, toString, toLocaleString, valueOf and isPrototypeOf.  It's called [DontEnumBug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute#JScript_DontEnum_Bug).