# toString does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tostring

I have a class in javascript which define the toString method,however when I want to print it in the page,it always print `[object object]` in IE(6-8).

But it works in firefox or chrome(they all print 'kk' in the example below).

I wonder why?

This is the example code:

```
function Person(name){
  this.name=name;
}
Person.prototype.toString=function(){
  return this.name;
}
var p=new Person('kk');
document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML=p.toString();
```

What is the problem?

---

BTW,this is the code in my application:

```
function inherit(pro) {
    function F() {};
    F.prototype = pro;
    return new F();
}
var Class = function() {
    var clazz = null,
    pros = {}; // root of chain
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var arg = arguments[i];

        if (typeof arg === "function") {
            arg = arg.prototype;
        } else {
            if (arg.init) {
                clazz = arg.init;
                delete arg.init;
            }
            var o = arg;
            arg = (function() {
                function F() {};
                F.prototype = pros;
                return new F;
            })();
            for (var key in o) arg[key] = o[key];
        }

        pros = arg;
    }

    clazz.prototype = pros;
    return clazz;
};

var Person = Class({
    init: function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    },
    toString: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
});

function init() {
    var p = new Person('kk');
    document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = p.toString();
}
window.onload = init;
```

Screen shot:

[image: IE]

[image: Firefox]

Comment: What do you mean by `it works`? What does it do in FF and Chrome?

Comment: The last line of your code, where it says `window.onload = init();`, is not correct/not what you expect it to do. This would execute the `init` function immediately, not when the window was load. Removing the `()` parentheses would be correct.

Comment: Fine,but the result does not change.

Comment: Just tried this last piece of code. It works in IE9, but it does show [object Object] in IEtester for IE8 and under though. Judging by the screenshot I think he is using IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see your issue now.

In **all** older version of IE (previous to 9) the javascript engine does **not** let you modify an element's prototype functions.

So the default `toString()` of an object is `[object Object]`

You might have to think of a different approach to your code for older versions of IE.

See article here: http://blog.motane.lu/2007/09/20/elementprototype-in-ie/

---

#### Final answer from comments below:

`.toString` is **already** a predefined function in the prototype of **all** objects, and it cannot be overridden in IE. Try using a different function name.

Comment: Now with the screenshot we believe you :-)

Comment: @Neal: I upload my screenshot as well. :(

Comment: @hguser what version of IE are you using?

Comment: @Neal:I test it in IE(6-8).Now,you should believe me. :)

Comment: @Neal:I read the article. However I did not add the toString method to the prototype of the HTML element. I add it in my custom class(function).

Comment: @hguser `.toString` is **already** a predefined function in the prototype of **all** objects, and it cannot be overridden in IE. Try using a different function name.

Answer (score 7):

Actually the comments above are not correct. Although you may not be able to override default prototype methods on elements, you CAN do it for your own types. The problem is that toString is not returned as a key in the code snippet:

```
for (var key in o) arg[key] = o[key];
```

if you add the following, things will work as expected:

```
if (o.toString !== Object.prototype.toString) {
   arg.toString = o.toString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can! You just gotta move the toString outside

```
Person.prototype.toString = function() { return this.name; }
```

Further info check this other post

[Issues with Object.toString in IE8, backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821354/issues-with-object-tostring-in-ie8-backbone-js)