# Javascript date shows nan in ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, nan

The code below works well in any browser except IE8. I am taking the time from a server and trying to display date string and server hour in IE8. What I get is for the string,serverHour, is undefined undefined undefined undefined, and for the hours, testHours, I get nan. I have tried using moment.js to get the date to display but I get the same result. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I have tried reformatting the date string several different ways, but I am unable to find a combination that works. I must be missing something very basic.

```
var xmlHttp;
var offset = 0;
var today = new Date();

/* 
return the standard time timezone offset regardless of whether the current time is on standard or daylight saving time. 
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?228309-Getting-server-date-time-with-no-server-side-script
*/
Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function () {
    var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
    return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
}

/*
Determine if the current time is on daylight saving time or not. We simply compare the current  timezone offset with the standard one. 
If they are equal then the current time is standard time. If they are not     then the current   time is daylight saving time. This second 
method will return true when the current time is daylight saving time and false when it is    standard time.
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?228309-Getting-server-date-time-with-no-server-       side-script
*/
Date.prototype.dst = function () {
    return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
}

// Convert GMT server time to Pacific time and return date.
function getServerTime(serverDateMs,offset) {
    var date = new Date(serverDateMs + offset * 3600 * 1000);
    return date;
}

// Function to get server time in GMT
function srvTime() {

// Create an XML object to collect information from server
try {
    //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (err1) {
    //IE
    try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    }
    catch (err2) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (err3) {
            //AJAX not supported, use CPU time.
            alert("AJAX not supported");
        }
    }
}

// Request information from the server using XML object
xmlHttp.open('POST', window.location.href, false);
xmlHttp.send();
return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
}
// Set offset if daylight savings time or standard time
if (today.dst() == true) { offset = -7; }
else { offset = -8; }

var x = srvTime();

//i have: Fri, 02 Jan 2015 22:54:05 GMT
// modify the string to remove comma and GMT
var dateString = x.replace(",", "").replace("GMT", "");

var a = dateString.split(" ");

//I want: Nov 06 2012 23:29:33 +0000
// reorganize to match above format
var newDatString = a[2] + " " + a[1] + " " + a[3] + " " + a[4];

// create the date object
var serverT = new Date(newDatString);
// get date/time in milliseconds
var serverDateMs = serverT.getTime();
// convert GMT time to pacific time
var serverDatePacific = getServerTime(serverDateMs, offset);
// create date object from pacific time
var serverHour = new Date(serverDatePacific);
// get hours from pacific time date object
var testHour = serverHour.getHours();
```

Comment: What is `serverDateMs`?

Comment: Could there be an issue with `window.location.href.toString()`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466156/tostring-does-not-work-in-ie

Comment: serverDateMS is the server time/date converted to milliseconds. Since I couldn't get any of the server info to show in ie8 for the client I stopped calling the function to test.

Comment: `nan` = `NaN`? If so... What line shows `NaN`? Could be more objective in showing where your problem? Your code does not  `console.log`, `alert` and not `document.write`. I don't know how we'll find out where is the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for not giving you the specific variables I am having trouble with. It's actually anything I derive from srvTime(). The only variable I really need is testHour and that one does give me nan when I use Document.write on my webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to test your code, since you did not say which variable goes to the "output" (the output would be the location in your code that displays `NaN`)

But did a test with the variables and realized that the problem is with your `XMLHttpRequest`.

`XMLHttpRequest` with 'POST' return headers like this (without Data header):

```
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3119
Last-Modified: Sun, 04 Jan 2015 03:38:27 GMT
```

But using `HEAD` method, return like this:

```
Date: Sun, 04 Jan 2015 03:41:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.3 (Win64)
Last-Modified: Sun, 04 Jan 2015 03:41:28 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

But this is not solution, because HEAD don't prevent cache and "sync-mode" is "bad".

If I understand your code, you want to get the server time without an interpreter language like Python, PHP, Ruby or another, the best way for this is to use Ajax (asynchronous).

> Synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` outside of workers is in the process of being removed from the web platform as it has detrimental effects to the end user's experience. (This is a long process that takes many years.) Developers must not pass false for the async argument when the JavaScript global environment is a document environment. User agents are strongly encouraged to warn about such usage in developer tools and may experiment with throwing an InvalidAccessError exception when it occurs. Read: http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Using "async mode", like this:

```
xmlHttp.open('HEAD', URL, true);//true = async
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () { ... };
```

[The HEAD method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.

So you can create an function using callback for get Date and use `new Date().getTime()` for prevent cache:

```
function getDateFromServer(done, fail) {
    var xmlHttp, uri, dateHeader;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new window.ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (ee1) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (ee2) {
                fail(-1, ee2.message);
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        fail(-1, "Your browser don't support XMLHttpRequest");
        return;
    }

    uri  = String(window.location);//Get same origin
    uri += uri.indexOf("?") !== -1 ? "&_=" : "?_=";
    uri += new Date().getTime();//Prevent cache

    xmlHttp.open("HEAD", uri, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
            dateHeader = xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
            if (dateHeader) {
                done(dateHeader);
            } else {
                fail(xmlHttp.status, "Date header is undefined");
            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

This function has two arguments, the first argument runs when ajax header return date and the second argument runs when you have error connecting to server or ISP.

Using code (note this is async, needed callback):

```
getDateFromServer(function (x) {//First argument is "done" callback
    alert(x);
    //put your code
}, function(status, msg) {//Second argument is "fail" callback
    alert("Error in request, error: " + status + " / " + msg);
});
```

Example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cy9kvsk/

Comment: I tried your function and I'm getting mixed results. I declared a global variable test and called the getDateFromServer function as shown below.

    getDateFromServer(function (x) {//First argument is "done" callback
        test = new Date(x).toUTCString();
          
    }, function (status) {//Second argument is "fail" callback
        alert("Error in request, error: " + status);
    });

When use I document.write("Server time is: " + test + "<br>"); 

I usually get undefined, but sometimes get the string I expect. I want to do more with the variable. Convert to pacifictiem. Can I?

Comment: One more comment. the test variable now shows undefined in ie11. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @vadorian put your code into first function `getDateFromServer(function (x) { **PUT YOUR CODE HERE** }, function(status) { alert("Error in request, error: " + status); });`

Comment: I think I have it working. This gets the code working for IE8, and I used a revision of my original code to get it working in current browser versions. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That is correct. the code didn't work for me in modern browsers.

Comment: Your code shows up perfectly in alerts and in the console, but when I try to save the anything to a variable and use document.write from the webpage I am getting undefined. I have the following _italic_ **bold** `getDateFromServer(function (x) {//First argument is "done" callback
    alert(x);
    var apple = new Date(x);
    test = apple.toUTCString();
    console.log("this is test " + test);
    console.log(new Date(x).toUTCString());
}, function (status) {//Second argument is "fail" callback
    alert("Error in request, error: " + status);
});`

And I want to print test to my webpage.

Comment: @vadorian I fixed code, get a exemple in jsfiddle (I update my answer).